# What's a better or more standard way to perform this function?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, methods, do-while

I am a java beginner, and in this particular problem I practiced making a program that converts any given string to lowercase string. Is there a a better way to achieve this goal in java (in terms of design)?

Also, how does the "else" (after "else if") catches or waits for me to make an input. Somehow that part does not make sense to me, even though I achieved what I wanted. How is the value of "ans" from input transferred to the entire loop and used until the loop is closed?

After many attempts and failures, I used a separate method for the conversion part. My second question is a bit too complicated to be researched.

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {

    public static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static String ans;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Conversion();

        do {
            ans = new String(s.nextLine());

            if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                Conversion();
            } else if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                out.println("Thank you for using this program!");
                break;
            } else {
                out.println("Invalid entry!");
                out.println("Would you like to convert another string?\n(Please type 'Y' for yes, or 'N' for no.)");
            }

        } while (ans != "N");

    }//END MAIN

    public static void Conversion() {
        out.println("Please enter string to be converted to lowercase: ");
        String str = new String(s.nextLine());
        out.println("Your new string is: " + str.toLowerCase());
        out.println("Would you like to convert another string? (Y/N)");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your first question:

- There are many design patterns and practices so many people can argue what I would recommend you to do. It's basically the same for all programming languages. Let's take your function "Conversion". The name itself says that you use it to convert stuff. Not to display, not to prompt - to convert. In this case, the only actual thing it should do is to convert upperCase to lowercase. In fact, you might want to specify what type of conversion it has in the name of the function (convertToLowerCase?). In fact, in Java, we use *lowerCamelCase* for all function names and *UpperCamelCase* for classes.
- If you accept my previous suggestion, you could break the `Conversion` function into multiple ones like `promptUserForInput`, `WrongInputHandler` and so forth.

If I understood your second question correctly, you wonder about the way the code executed and how the variable `ans` is transferred further into the loop. Let's take a look at your code and what variables do:

1. You initialize your variable in the class `MyClass` by making it accessible to all methods in the class;
2. You prompt the user for the input to assign to this variable inside the do..while loop with this line `ans = new String(s.nextLine());` which saves the value of the variable and, again, which can be accessed inside the whole class so its value is changed.
3. It goes into the if..else if...else statement. The way it works, it goes line by line - if the first *if-statement* fails, it goes on until it finds a **truthy** statement and it doesn't go any further. In your case, if the `ans` is not equal to either y/Y/ it will go to `else if` statement and if it's not n/N, it will go to else (so basically whatever except y/Y/n/N) and will be executed. After that, it jumps into the `while (ans!= "N");` line where it compares your class-member variable `ans` and if it's not equal to "N" it starts over the loop right after the `do{` part until you type in the "N".

I hope that makes sense. Whenever the program is asking you for input, it does not execute code further but is stuck until you provide any input. The value from input **itself isn't passed** throughout the loop and the program. The reason why you can use it because you created a higher-scope variable `ans` where you saved the result of your input.

**IMPORTANT**: if you've declared the `ans` **inside** the do..while loop, you would've not been able to have accessed it in the `while (ans...)` because it will 'die' right before the curly brace between do { ...***here***} while(). If you want to learn more about the scope and variables in general, you can read [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/).

Here is my code example:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    //declare before entering the loop to have higher scope
    String ans = "y";

    do {

        //we get the given string to convert from the user
        String str = promptForString();
        //we convert the string
        str = converseStringToLowerCase(str);

        //display the string (could use another function for that: easier to debug and locate problems and in bigger projects)
        out.println("Your new string is: " + str);

        //prompt user for respond to continue or not
        ans = promptForContinue();

        handleResponse(ans);

    } while (!ans.equals("n"));

}//END MAIN

//prompts user for an input string
public static String promptForString() {
    out.println("Please enter string to be converted to lowercase: ");
    String str = new String(s.nextLine());  
    return str;
}

//converts any given string to lower case
public static String converseStringToLowerCase(String str) {
    return str.toLowerCase();
}

//is used to prompt user for reply
public static String promptForContinue() {
    out.println("Would you like to convert another string? (Y/N)");
    String str = new String(s.nextLine());

    //is good to make if...else statements easier - it will always be lower case (or upper if you prefer)
    return str.toLowerCase();
}

//easier to locate other response scenarios
public static void handleResponse(String response) {
    if (response.equals("n")) {
            out.println("Thank you for using this program!");

           //it's not a very good practice to innaturally break loops. Use input for that in while(..) statement
           // break;
        } else if (!response.equals("y")) {
            out.println("Invalid entry!");
            out.println("Would you like to convert another string?\n(Please type 'Y' for yes, or 'N' for no.)");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I notice a few issues; `Conversion` looks like a class-name (Java naming convention would be `conversion`) and `ans != "N"` is using `==` instead of `.equals` - and wouldn't ignore case (`!ans.equalsIgnoreCase("N")`). Globals (e.g. `static`) are *bad* (pass the `Scanner` to the methods that need it), and the `static import` just makes the code more difficult to reason about (in my opinion). Your current loop doesn't really follow a conventional form, I would extract the prompt and loop for "another" conversion to a new method and if you must print a thank you I'd do so after the "main loop". Something like,

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        conversion(sc);
    } while (another(sc));
    System.out.println("Thank you for using this program!");
}

public static void conversion(Scanner s) {
    System.out.println("Please enter string to be converted to lowercase: ");
    System.out.printf("Your new string is: %s%n", s.nextLine().toLowerCase());
}

public static boolean another(Scanner s) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Would you like to convert another string? (Y/N)");
        String ans = s.nextLine();
        if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            return true;
        } else if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
            return false;
        }
        System.out.println("Invalid entry!");
        System.out.println("(Please type 'Y' for yes, or 'N' for no.)");
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer. To add, Scanner is a Closeable object and therefore must be closed via Scanner#close or in a try-with-resources.

Comment: @Jason In general, yes. However, when the `Scanner` wraps `System.in` (a global) that is a resource you *generally* want to leave open (closing the `Scanner` would also `close()` `System.in`).

Comment: Ouuuuuuu nice catch, oopsies